# error in my code

Tags: android

I have problem in my code in the commented lines:

```
 bouton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            url=edit.getText().toString();
            System.out.println(url);

            // this line and
            Intent Activite=new Intent(this, Main1.class);

            Activite.putExtra("param", url);

            /// this line
            this.startActivityForResult(Activite, 1000);
        }
        });
```

Can you help me to correct my code

Comment: What problem? What error? What is Main1.class, does it exist? What is edit? Give us more to go on, we can't help you this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

either remove `this` from the line where you are starting the next activity.

OR

use:

```
ClassName.this.startActivityForResult(Activite, 1000);
```

Basically when you are saying this : `this.startActivityForResult(Activite, 1000);` "this" is corresponding to the context of OnClickListener and not of the Activity you are in. As you already know that `startActivityForResult` is a method on `Activity` class and not of `android.view.View.OnClickListener` class.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to mudit, replace

> Intent Activite=new Intent(this, Main1.class);

with `Intent Activite=new Intent(ActivityClassName.this, Main1.class);`

But Levisaxos was right, you could give us more info, at least your stack trace